# gdb Debugger stuck on 62% during initialization in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I am new to coding and trying to get eclipse neon running on my macbook air. I am having trouble getting the debugger to work. I installed gdb with homebrew, created a certificate and signed gdb as per the instructions in the link:

https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/mac-gdb-install.html

I then configured eclipse debugger settings with the location of the newly installed gdb. However now when I try to start the debugger, the initialization process starts but gets stuck forever on 62%. Any tips on how to solve this? Could it be a memory issue? MBA has 4gb RAM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in CDT - [Bug #509737](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509737)

The problem in summary is that **CDT version 9.2.0** cannot work with **GDB version 7.12**.
One way to resolve this is to use an older version of GDB, for example **GDB version 7.11**
Another way to workaround this is to pretend GDB 7.12 is actually version 7.11.
Create the following executable script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "--version" ]; then
  echo "GNU gdb (Debian 7.11-1) 7.11"
  exit
fi
exec /usr/local/bin/gdb "$@"
```

and configure eclipse to run it instead of gdb.